# From where may I download the Flash Builder SDK equivalent to Flash Player 11?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder, flash, mxmlc

I wish to use Stage3D and Context3D in ActionScript. For that I need to download the beta version of Flash Player 11. However, I can't find the equivalent Flash Builder SDK with the mxmlc executable that can compile ActionScript into Flash 11 capable Shockwave Flash files. Any clue as to where I may download it from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need another SDK you need to modify the flex-config.xml file and add additional parameter to your mxmlc command. Look in sdks\4.5.1\frameworks\flex-config.xml and change the target-player node the swf-version to 13 and the node path-element to the correct playerglobal.swc (available on labs.adobe.com).

The compiler parameter is "-target-player=11.0.0" (if your flex-config.xml reflect that version).

Comment: There's a download link for the playerglobal.swc at http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html